# Union of two connected sets where the intersecion of closure of one and the other is connected.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Suppose $H$ and $H'$ are two connected topological subspaces such that $cl(H) \cap H' \neq \emptyset$, then $H \cup H'$ is connected.

This is my attempt:

Suppose $A$ and $B$ open and not empty in $H \cup H'$ such that $H \cup H' \subset A \cup B$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

Then we have that $H \subset A$ or $H \subset B$ and likewise with $H'$ (otherwise they would not be connected). If $H \cup H' \subset A$ or $B$ then $A$ or $B$ would be empty. Let's suppose $H \subset A$ and $H' \subset B$. Let's choose $x \in cl(H) \cap H' \neq \emptyset$. $x \in H' \subset B$, and because $B$ is open, $B$ is a neighborhood of $x$, so $B \cap H \neq \emptyset$ contradicting the fact that $H \subset A$.

Is it correct?

Comment: Why must $H \subset A$ or $H \subset B$? That is unjustified

Comment: @balddraz Because if $H \not\subset A$ then $H \cap A$ and $H \cap B$ would be two separated sets of $H$ contradicting the fact that it's connected. Edited the answer.

Comment: If $H \subset A \cup B$ and H is not in A (or B) entirely would mean by definition that $H$ is not connected. The proof seems correct.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct. Another option: let $\phi:H\cup H'\to D$ be any continuous function, $D$ a discrete space. As $H$ is connected, $\phi$ is constant on $H$, say constantly equal to $d$. From the fact $\phi(\overline{H})\subseteq\overline{\phi(H)}=\{d\}$ we know $\phi$ is constantly $d$ on $\overline{H}$ too. Note also that $\phi$ is constant on $H'$, and $\overline{H}\cap H'\neq\emptyset$ forces that constant to be $d$. Hence, $\phi\equiv d$ constantly; as $(\phi,D)$ is arbitrary it follows $H\cup H'$ is connected.